# Magento 2.2.4 to 2.2.6

Tags: magento2

I have a website developed Magento 2.2.4 and I want to export this website all data i.e `customer,product,review etc` and import this data into the Magento 2.2.6 site.

How can i do this ?

Thanks is Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps to upgrade your Magento 2.2.4 to 2.2.6

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update
composer update

rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/generation/

bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

After this,First uninstall your porto theme and then you can install the Fastest theme and third party extensions from your Magento 2.2.6 existing instance to your upgraded version 2.2.6

Comment: Hello, Both are the different database. How to transfare the data ?

Comment: Magento 2.2.4 have a porto theme and Magento 2.2.6 have a fastest theme

Comment: Follow the steps I have mentioned in edited answer

Comment: Porto theme is deleted ?

Comment: Using this steps ?

Comment: You have to uninstalled porto theme after upgrade finished, then install fastest theme and third party extension

Comment: OK, I will try it